# Why is my Application not running on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-xp, .net-framework-version

i've got a question about my application,

its a .net framework 4.0 one and I created it in Visual Studio 2022.

My Application should run on windows XP but it doesnt work.

> > application.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

But when I start my application on windows 10 and look in the task manager it says

> > application(32bit)

I already installed the Dotnet 4.0 runtime on Xp

Comment: What's the output of `dumpbin /headers application.exe`? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/headers

Comment: Given that XP has been out of support for almost 10 years, and .net 4.0 for almost as long, you should have no expectation that it should work. If you need to develop for unsupported platforms you might want to replicate the development environment from that time. And completely isolate it from the internet since it will be insecure. If you want to support both the latest win 10 and XP, you better hope nothing breaks, or that you can fix the issues yourself, since you will get no support from Microsoft.

Comment: Run the following command-line tool on your executable: `dumpbin <yourexename> /headers` and then look at  the value for `subsystem version` under `OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES`. That specifies the minimum OS version it will run on. What value does it show for your exe?

Comment: What is you target project setting?  Window XP is only 32 bit and usually default setting is 64 bit.